# nested do-while loop and while-loop

Tags: visual-c++

In this program, choices other than 0 to 4 are all invalid so the user is asked for his/her choice again and again. Then, as choice "1" is entered, the program would perform addition of two numbers. Therefore, it would proceed to ask for the two numbers (x and y) and then print out the calculation result.The user can then choose to perform another calculation. As long as the user does not choose the choice "5" to quit the program, the program would continue to do different calculations chosen by the user.I want to exit the program when choice == 5 . Yet it only returns me "Your choice is invalid, please enter again." Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int choice, x, y, z;

do
{
    cout << "Math is easy!" << endl << "1. Perform addition" << endl << "2. Perform subtraction" << endl <<
        "3. Perform multiplication" << endl << "4. Perform division" << endl << "5. Quit" << endl << "Please enter your choice[1 - 5]:" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 4)
    {
        cerr << "Your choice is invalid, please enter again.";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    cout << "Please enter x:" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please enter y:" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        z = x + y;
        cout << x << "+" << y << "=" << z << endl;
    }
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        z = x - y;
        cout << x << "-" << y << "=" << z << endl;
    }
    if (choice == 3)
    {
        z = x * y;
        cout << x << "*" << y << "=" << z << endl;
    }
    if (choice == 4)
    {
        z = x / y;
        cout << x << "+" << y << "=" << z << endl;
    }



} while (choice != 5);
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

How should I do?

Comment: You see, I hope, that when you enter 5, your "while" loop rejects it and asks again. So you need some special code to check for 5 before that while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Before while loop you can check `if(choice == 5)` and  `break;`

```
if(choice == 5)// if choice == 5 break loop. or exit(0);
    break;
while (choice < 1 || choice > 4)
{
    cerr << "Your choice is invalid, please enter again.";
    cin >> choice;
}
.
.
.
.
if (choice == 1)
{
    z = x + y;
    cout << x << "+" << y << "=" << z << endl;
}
else if (choice == 2)
{
   //code
}
else if (choice == 3)
{
   //code
}
```

Use `if - elseif` instead of using multiple `if` condition. you can also use `switch`.